# A single foreach statement which iterates over two collections

Tags: c#, collections

So I have two collections - one of `int?`, and one of `string`.

I want to iterate over both, and I have a good chunk of code that I want to perform to each. However there are some slight differences. if the value is an `int?`, some additional code is needed.

I'm trying to follow DRY principles, so I don't want to rewrite my code. I also don't want to put it in an external function, as this is already abstracted away from my MVC app controller  code and I don't want it getting needlessly complex.

Is there a way to do something like this in c#

```
foreach(object o in (ints && strings))
{
    if(o is int)
    {
        // do in specific stuff
    }

    // do all my generic stuff.    
}
```

EDIT:
It's actually `int?` not `int`. when I try and combine them into a generic list of type `List<object>` I get an error

Comment: This should work as is, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Asad: Why should `ints && strings` work?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Oh, missed that bit. Just needs a `.Concat`. I was focusing on the `is`.

Comment: DRY does not mean that your are allowed to write only one foreach loop per program. What you are trying to do, _as described here_ makes no sense. Just have two loops. In order to not repeat the body, extract it into a method and call that method from the two loops.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten thanks, I understand that. I was trying to avoid extracting it out into a method, which *would* mean I'd have to repeat myself in the second loop.

Comment: What is wrong with calling a method from two places? The whole idea of DRY is that you refactor common code into methods (and objects), so that they can be called from more than one place.

Comment: IMO calling methods from several places doesn't violates DRY

Comment: @roryok You don't necessarily have to include multiple method calls if you decide to extract it into a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this particular structure, you can combine them into one big object collection using `Concat`, like:

```
foreach (object o in ints.Cast<object>().Concat(strings.Cast<object>()))
```

But I'd probably suggest breaking out your functionality into a method, and running two loops:

```
foreach (int i in ints) {
    DoSomething(i);
    DoSomethingWithInt(i);
}

foreach (string s in strings) {
    DoSomething(s);
    DoSomethingWithString(s);
}
```

That will keep things clean and a little more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I wasn't going to put things in an external method but based on all the answers including yours suggesting it, I think I will go that route.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be cleaner to put the generic stuff in a common function, then loop over both collections. That way you get rid of the somewhat odd if int stuff.

```
foreach(int number in ints)
{
    // do int specific stuff    
    GeneralFunction(number);
}

foreach(string stringValue in strings)
{
    GeneralFunction(number);
}
```

Comment: I approve of your avatar =)

Answer (score 1):

This could also work for you:

```
IEnumerator en1 = ints.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator en2 = strings.GetEnumerator();

while((en1.MoveNext()) && (en2.MoveNext()))
{
     WhateverActionWithNullableInt((int?)en1.Current);
     WhateverActionWithString((string)en2.Current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
foreach (object o in ints.Cast<object>().Concat(strings))
{
    if (o is int)
    {
        // do in specific stuff
    }

    // do all my generic stuff.    
}
```

I would separate it into functions and take advantage of overloading myself, but you said you didn't want to do that.

Comment: I don't think the second cast is needed. Enumerables are covariant, so `IEnumerable<string>` is acceptable where `IEnumerable<object>` is required.

Comment: @Asad You are absolutely right. Removing it makes it harder to read (for me) but it could improve performance, so I'll accept it as a desirable change. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new list, which is the concatenation of the two lists :

**EDIT**

```
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        List<int> ints = new List<int>(); ints.Add(74); ints.Add(47);
        List<string> strings = new List<string>(); strings.Add("hello"); strings.Add("hello2");
        list.AddRange(ints.Cast<object>());
        list.AddRange(strings.Cast<object>());

        foreach (object o in list)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(o);
            if (o is int)
            {
                // do in specific stuff
            }

            // do all my generic stuff.    
        }
```

Comment: tried this and it didn't work. I got an error trying to add the ints to the list

Comment: @Fabien The `Add` method adds a single item to the collection. You're trying to add two other lists as items in your objects list, which will result in unexpected behavior.